# Image retrieval in imageview

Tags: android, bitmap, camera

I have a problem using camera intent when i capture image in portrait mode and display in imageview then imageview always display in landscape mode.as shown in the code below, and also it displays the image in Bitmap which I dont want, i need the same image on imageview that is captured with camera.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");
    imv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
}

public void cameera(View v) {
    Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(camera_intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        Bitmap capturedImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imv.setImageBitmap(capturedImage);

    }
}
```